# Calculate the Line Integral of a Vector over a Closed Path

Tags: calculus, geometry, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, vector-analysis

I was working on the problem attached in the image below, which asks to calculate the integral over the closed path in the figure. The integral is $$\oint \vec A \cdot d\vec l $$ where $\vec A = r\cos\phi\,\hat{r} + \sin\phi\,\hat{\phi}$. So I tried letting the vector be in the original form and tried to come up with an equation for the path in polar coordinates. I found the arclength but I'm not able to make it work. Or should I try to switch the vector into cartesian coordinates? Any help is welcomed!

The image:

[image: The image]

Comment: You can split the integral into 
$$\begin{aligned}\oint \vec A \cdot \mathrm{d}\vec l = &\int_{\pi / 3}^{\pi / 6}{A_\phi \, r\, \mathrm{d}\phi}\Big|_{r = 2} + \int_2^5{A_r \, \mathrm{d}r}\Big|_{\phi = \pi / 6}\\
+ &\int_{\pi / 6}^{\pi / 3}{A_\phi \, r\,\mathrm{d}\phi}\Big|_{r = 5} + \int_5^2{A_r \, \mathrm{d}r}\Big|_{\phi = \pi / 3}\,\text{.}\end{aligned}$$
Does that help?

Comment: @Lemmon, Certainly did. If you prefer, write an answer explaining your derivation and I can accept it.